# format-default : The collection has not been initialized. PowerShell + SharePoint Online Error

Tags: powershell, csv, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a problem with my PowerShell script. Script removes records from SharePoint List and adds new records from csv afterwards.
Basically when I run the script line by line all works fine. But when I try to run the whole thing I get this error:

> format-default : The collection has not been initialized. It has not
> been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
> explicitly requested.
> + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], CollectionNotInitializedException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand

Here's my code:

```
$list_modified = 'list_name'
$filename = "C:\.......\file.csv"

# Purge existing records in list
$records = Get-PnPListItem -List $list_modified -PageSize 500

# make sure fields in list have corresponding field in csv and same data type
Get-PnPField -List $list_modified

# purge list
foreach ($record in $records)
{
    Write-Host "Removing Id "  $record.Id
    Remove-PnPListItem -List $list_modified -Identity $record.Id -Force
}

Get-PnPField -List $list_modified
$records = Get-PnPListItem -List $list_modified -PageSize 500
$records | measure

# Import csv
$csv_data = Import-CSV -Path $filename -Delimiter `t

foreach ($row in $csv_data) {
  Add-PnPListItem -List $list_modified -Values @{
  "Title" = $row.'name';
  "uuid" = $row.'uuid';
  "name" = $row.'name';
  "short_description" = $row.'short_description';
  "logo_url" = $row.'logo_url';
  "homepage_url" = $row.'homepage_url';
  "category_groups_list" = $row.'category_groups_list';
  "category_list" = $row.'category_list';
  "total_funding_usd" = $row.'total_funding_usd';
  "last_funding_on" = $row.'last_funding_on'
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Help please!

Thanks!
Maciej

Comment: Have you considered posting about your issue as an issue on the github page for the pnp powershell cmdlets?  They might be able to help you with your issue:   https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell

Comment: Also, I am not sure if this would have much of an effect, but concerning the way in which you have written the hashtable in the "add-pnplistitem" cmdlet, can you try formatting it differently?  Try formatting it like this:     Title = "$($row.Name)"       #exclude all of the ";", as the new line will separate the values

Comment: In order for us to help you better, it would also help to know where in the script the error is occurring.  Consider putting a couple of Write-host "<line num>" functions in your script to identify where the error is occurring so we can isolate what is throwing the error.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamHiggs! It crashes at Line 28: Add-PnPListItem -List $list_modified -Values

Answer (score 2):

A Google search for the following finds a number of similar issues:

> format-default : The collection has not been initialized

from: https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/799#issuecomment-618926331

**Try returning your statement into a variable.**

Do this

```
$item = Add-PnPListItem -List $list -ContentType "Project" -Values $Values**
```

and

```
$item = Set-PnPListItem -List $list -Identity $targetItem.Id -Values $Values**
```

Comment: Thanks @Matthew! Could you help to implement this into the code? I'm new to PowerShell and don't know how to make use of this. Tried something like in the comment below, but with same effect:

Comment: `$item = Add-PnPListItem -List $list_modified -ContentType "Project" -Values @{
    "uuid" = $row.'uuid';
    "news_company" = $row.'news_company';
    "Title" = $row.'title';
    "posted_on" = $row.'posted_on';
    "logo_url" = $row.'logo_url';
    "url" = $row.'url';
    "source" = $row.'Source'
    }

foreach ($row in $csv_data) {$item}`